# Multiple conditional ion-header-bar 's overlapping ion-content

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm fighting with header bars.

**This snippet works perfectly fine:**

```
   <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">mytitle</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-view view-title="">
        <ion-content>
          MyContent
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </ion-pane>
```

Once I add two additional header bars for different conditions, my `ion-content` module doesn't get the `has-header` class and my header bar overlaps my content.

**As said, this crashes my design:**

```
   <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" ng-show="conditionA()">
        <h1 class="title">mytitle1</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" ng-show="conditionB()">
        <h1 class="title">mytitle2</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" ng-show="conditionC()">
        <h1 class="title">mytitle3</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-view view-title="">
        <ion-content>
          MyContent
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </ion-pane>
```

Setting the `has-header` class manually doesn't solve the problem. The class gets removed by angular/ionic.
What am I doing wrong? It should be possible to set different headers, shouldn't it? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ng-show` to `ng-if` and it works:

(P.S.: see the snippet in full screen)

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
 
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    
    $scope.head = 1;
    $scope.change = function(n) {
      $scope.head = n;
    }

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="head=1">

  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <h1 class="title">mytitle1</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" ng-if="head==1">
      <h1 class="title">mytitle1</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" ng-if="head==2">
      <h1 class="title">mytitle2</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive" ng-if="head==3">
      <h1 class="title">mytitle3</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content >
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <button class="button button-positive button-primary" ng-click="change(1)">to head 1</button>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <button class="button button-positive button-primary" ng-click="change(2)">to head 2</button>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <button class="button button-positive button-primary" ng-click="change(3)">to head 3</button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ng-show/hide merely hides them with css, but they are still present in the dom, which means your view has multiple headers. ng-if will physically remove anything that doesn't match, which is what you want here. You can readup on the difference between display:none and visibility:hidden in css, because that is the exact difference here.